# Adding a random number into my singly linked list, but it always adds the same randomized number

Tags: java, random, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm making a singly linked list, and the numbers I am adding into the list need to be random. I can't seem to get a randomized number every time, it instead prints the same randomized number 10 times when I need it to be different random numbers.

I understand this is happening because the random number is only assigned once, but how do I make it change every time?

```
    //Creating a random number between 1 and 107
    static Random rnum = new Random();
    static int randomNumber = rnum.nextInt((107- 1) + 1);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Producer List
        SinglyLinkedList pList = new SinglyLinkedList();
        
        // Add random nodes to the list 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pList.addNode(randomNumber);
        }
```

The output of the code would be "71 71 71 71 71 (repeated)" and I just want to figure out how to make it a different number every time! Please help!

Comment: Your code called the `rnum.nextInt` method only one time.  Have you considered moving it inside the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing one randomly generated number, you should generate a new random number for each iteration in your loop. It's also a good idea to seed the Random object with the current time

```
static Random rnum = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
//static int randomNumber = rnum.nextInt((107- 1) + 1);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Producer List
    SinglyLinkedList pList = new SinglyLinkedList();
    
    // Add random nodes to the list 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pList.addNode((rNum.nextInt(106) + 1));
    }
```

Comment: that did it! Thank you! :)

Comment: @ckcp When you get a chance please click the arrow next to this answer to mark the question as solved

Comment: `pList.addNode(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 107));`

Comment: Passing `System.currentTimeMillis()` is likely much worse than using the default seed.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I understand this is happening because the random number is only assigned once, but how do I make it change every time? ..."*

Use a *method*.

```java
static int randomNumber() {
    return rnum.nextInt((107- 1) + 1);
}
```

Or, an *[IntSupplier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html)*.

```java
static IntSupplier randomNumber = (() -> rnum.nextInt((107- 1) + 1));
```

```java
randomNumber.getAsInt()
```

Or use a *stream*.

```java
rnum.ints(10, 0, 108).forEach(pList::addNode);
```